# Why my app crashes when I use if condition in my oncreate?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to dynamically change my UI by checking some condition in my onCreate activity . But my app crashes .

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.busdetail);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        String s=i.getStringExtra("fname");
        Log.d("ssssss: ",s);
        if(s=="itemName1")
        {
           for(int k=0;k<itemName1.length;k++)
           {
               arrayk[k]=itemName1[k];
           }
        }

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, arrayk, imageId);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //String selectedItem = itemName[+position];
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(BusDetail.this, AddComment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here `if (s=="itemName1")` then I copy `itemName1` into arrayk. Both itemName1 and arrayk are string array . But when I clicked an item, my app crashes. When I avoid if condition block then my app runs well.

Comment: Please be more specific. What error message/call stack is thrown on "crash"?

Comment: Don't do that: `s=="itemName1"`, use `s.equals("itemName1")` instead. What is `itemName1`? Where is it initialized? Same question for `arrayk`.

Comment: if(i != null) ... if(s!=null)

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, to compare a `String`, don't use `==` ! You have to compare the value of the `String`, not the object itself. Your condition is wrong now... `==` compares the object references but not the content.

Use the following condition: `if(s.equals("itemName1"))`
or use `equalsIgnoreCase("itemName1")` if you want to ignore the case.

Then Remember that during the `onCreate`, your UI is not ready yet. If you have any change to do in the UI, do it in the `onCreateView`

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

`onCreateView` is working this way:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 

    View mainview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);

    //mainview is your main view, use it to find your elements, assign them listeners, change text, attributes, etc

    return mainview; //you have to return this view

    }
```

It is basically working like onCreate except that this is were you have to manage everything linked to your views and to your UI. It's also there that you have to inflate the view you need, and to return it.

Comment: i use if(s.equals("itemName1")) ... but this time app crashes also

Comment: How i use onCreateView in this code please explain .